# Use object method as a callback t and pass data to the method in PHP

Tags: php

I have a class which uses Curl's `beforeSend` callback. Here it is:

```
$curl->beforeSend(function() use ($exchanger, $ratesUpdate) {
    ExchangerRatesUpdate::create([
        'exchanger_id'    => $exchanger->id,
        'rates_update_id' => $ratesUpdate->id
    ]);
});
```

I want to refactor this piece of code a bit by extracting the logic inside callback to its own method, for example: `private function beforeSend($exchanger, $ratesUpdate)` and call it in `$cur->beforeSend`.

How can I do this? I found other answers saying that I can pass an array, like `[$this, 'beforeSend']`, however it throws an error (Creating default object from empty value) and also I couldn't find how can I pass arguments to the method.

This approach works, however it looks like I do double work by passing arguments array twice:

```
        $curl->beforeSend(function() use ($exchanger, $ratesUpdate) {
            call_user_func_array([$this, 'beforeXmlFetching'], [
                'exchanger'   => $exchanger,
                'ratesUpdate' => $ratesUpdate
            ]);
        });
```

Comment: PHP's curl doesn't have a OO interface so what curl wrapper are you using?

Comment: I use php-curl-class/php-curl-class, but the question is more general, I just didn't have much practice with callbacks. So imagine I have some kind of object with a lot of callbacks, and I want to somehow put every callback logic into its own class method...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I answer your question, but in your specific case, you can implement a [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

```
class ExchangerRatesUpdateBuilder
{
    protected $exchanger;
    protected $ratesUpdate;

    public function build()
    {
        return ExchangerRatesUpdate::create([
            'exchanger_id'    => $this->exchanger->id,
            'rates_update_id' => $this->ratesUpdate->id
        ]);
    }

    public function setExchanger($exchanger)
    {
        $this->exchanger = $exchanger;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setRatesUpdate($ratesUpdate)
    {
        $this->ratesUpdate = $ratesUpdate;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

In your script, you have to instanciate the builder like this (like a service):

```
$builder = new ExchangerRatesUpdateBuilder()
```

When you're calling the $curl->beforeSend() method, you can passe the 'build' callback :

```
$curl->beforeSend([$builder->setExchanger($exchanger)->setRatesUpdate($ratesUpdate), 'build']);
```